# Cannot take screen lock with password off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens

On my Samsung Galaxy S3, when I try to take off the password and change to swipe everything is greyed out so I went to clear credentials and that also is greyed out.

How can I remove the screen lock?

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot 2]

<sup>Click image(s) for larger version</sup>

Comment: Can you add screenshots?

Comment: How do I add screenshots?

Comment: Hold on power button... You should see Take screenshot option.

Comment: Try this... Navigate to Menu>Settings>Applications>All apps>Settings>Clear data & Cache.

Comment: Yeah I tried it and i don't have a clear data and cache settings under all apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ones too...
*** Settings -> Security -> Deactivate Administrators. Deactivate anything listed (including Android Device Manager, you can activate it later on).**
After that...
*** Settings -> Security -> Clear credentials.**

Comment: Oh thank you thank you thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: Glad it worked. You can mark this as an answer by clicking on tick mark provided.